# How should i import a c extension function i wrote into a sibling module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, directory-structure, python-packaging

I'm developing a package that has c extensions and some pure python modules in the same package. (maybe this is the real problem and they shouldn't be in the same package?)
the project structure looks like this right now

```
(winlin) godel@recurser:~/personal/projects/winlin$ tree
.
├── dist
│   ├── winlin-1.0-cp310-cp310-linux_x86_64.whl
│   ├── winlin-1.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
│   ├── winlin-1.0-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
│   ├── winlin-1.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
│   └── winlin-1.0.tar.gz
├── docker
│   ├── build_wheels.sh
│   ├── containers.yml
│   ├── docker-compose.yml
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── README.md
│   └── setup_docker.sh
├── LICENSE
├── manylinx.sh
├── pyproject.toml
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.py
├── src
│   └── winlin
│       ├── experiment.c
│       ├── window.py
│       └── winlin.c
└── tests
    └── test.py

5 directories, 21 files
```

So if I want to use the functionality provided by `winlin.c` in `window.py` what is the canonical way to approach this problem? I'm currently just doing `import winlin` in `window.py`

i mean the c functions I wrote won't exist until I the codes been compiled so for now what I'm doing is installing the package and then just importing from it but that seems like a hacky anti pattern to me, I'm just not sure what else to do.

this is my `setup.py` file

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension

winlin = Extension(
    'winlin',
    define_macros = [('MAJOR_VERSION', '1'),('MINOR_VERSION', '0')],
    include_dirs = ['/usr/local/include/', '/usr/include/glib-2.0', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include', '/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include'],
    libraries = ['xdo', 'glib-2.0', 'X11'],
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib/'],
    sources = ['src/winlin/winlin.c', 'src/winlin/experiment.c']
)

setup(
  name = 'winlin',
  version = '1.0',
  description = 'A tool kit for manipulating windows in linux',
  ext_modules = [winlin]
)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what else you would do.  Somehow, you need to compile the code into a DLL, and then import that DLL.  You either do that by hand, or you let setuptools do it for you.

Comment: Modules are modules, the importer doesn’t care how they are implemented. If you want to import a sibling, that’s `import .winlin` (mind the dot).

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks! this is my first foray into c so its at least nice to know I'm not way off base!

Comment: Mind, if you are actually asking "how do I directly import from a C *source code* file", that’s something else. You might want to [edit] the question to make sure it’s clear what you need. Note though that this has likely been asked before.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I don't think thats what I'm asking because there's no way to import from that file until its compiled (as far as I know)

Comment: @gnarlyninja Well, I'm not sure what you are asking, either – but ideally, you should know. Anyways, in principle it *is* possible to let the import machinery run arbitrary code and thus even compile things; that's how [Cython supports imports from uncompiled source code](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#compiling-with-pyximport). Just because the import machinery doesn't know how doesn't mean that one cannot tell it how.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi the link you added is for cython which is a different implementation of python than C python

Comment: @gnarlyninja No, Cython compiles to modules for CPython (and other interpreters). It plugs into the implementation, it is not a separate one.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi ah my mistake. But its still outside of my tool chain